# How can I replace the mouseout event with touchend for iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, mobile-safari, dom-events

It seems from the [Safari docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) docs that I should be able to add an event listener to an element in order to get a touchend event to fire (I have assumed this to be the event which happens when the user lifts their finger having first touched the element).

However, I am not getting the desired behaviour with this code:

```
/* 

    Easy Scroll v1.0
    written by Alen Grakalic, provided by Css Globe (cssglobe.com)
    please visit http://cssglobe.com/post/1495/easy-scroll-accessible-content-scroller

*/

this.easyscroll = function(){

    // id of the container element 
    var id = "myContent";

    // navigation buttons text
    //dave var nav = ["Scroll Up", "Scroll Down", "Reset"];
    var nav = ["Scroll Up", "Scroll Down"];

    //  id for each navigation button (OPTIONAL)
    //dave var navId = ["btnUp", "btnDown", "btnReset"];
     var navId = ["btnUp", "btnDown"];

    // movement speed
    var speed = 10;

    // desired height of the container element (in pixels)
    var height = 300;

    //
    // END CONFIG
    // do not edit below this line (unless you want to of course :) )
    //

    var obj = document.getElementById(id);

    obj.up = false;
    obj.down = false;
    obj.fast = false;

    var container = document.createElement("div");
    var parent = obj.parentNode;
    container.id="easyscroll";
    parent.insertBefore(container,obj);
    parent.removeChild(obj);    

    container.style.position = "relative";
    container.style.height = height + "px";
    container.style.overflow = "hidden";
    obj.style.position = "absolute";
    obj.style.top = "0";
    obj.style.left = "0";
    container.appendChild(obj);

    var btns = new Array();
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.id="easyscrollnav";
    for (var i=0;i<nav.length;i++){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = nav[i];
        li.id = navId[i];
        btns.push(li);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }

    parent.insertBefore(ul,container);

    btns[0].onmouseover = function(){
        obj.up = true;
        this.className = "over";
    };
    btns[0].onmouseout = function(){
        obj.up = false;
        this.className = "";
    };      
    btns[1].onmouseover = function(){
        obj.down = true;
        this.className = "over";        
    };
    btns[1].onmouseout = function(){
        obj.down = false;
        this.className = "";
    };      
    btns[0].onmousedown = btns[1].onmousedown = function(){
        obj.fast = true;
    };  
    btns[0].onmouseup = btns[1].onmouseup = function(){
        obj.fast = false;
    };


    btns[0].addEventListener("touchend", function(){
        obj.up = false;
    }, false);
    btns[1].addEventListener("touchend", function(){
        obj.down = false;
    }, false);

    //btns[2].onmouseover = function(){         
    //  this.className = "over";
//  };  
    //btns[2].onmouseout = function(){      
        //this.className = "";
    //};        
    //btns[2].onclick = function(){         
    //  obj.style.top = "0px";
//  };      

    this.start = function(){                
        var newTop;
        var objHeight = obj.offsetHeight;
        var top = obj.offsetTop;
        var fast = (obj.fast) ? 2 : 1;
        if(obj.down){        
            newTop = ((objHeight+top) > height) ? top-(speed*fast) : top;   
            obj.style.top = newTop + "px";
        };  
        if(obj.up){      
            newTop = (top < 0) ? top+(speed*fast) : top;
            obj.style.top = newTop + "px";
        };
    };  
    obj.interval = setInterval("start()",50);       

};


//
// script initiates on page load. 
//

this.addEvent = function(obj,type,fn){
    if(obj.attachEvent){
        obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
        obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn](window.event );}
        obj.attachEvent('on'+type, obj[type+fn]);
    } else {
        obj.addEventListener(type,fn,false);
    };
};
addEvent(window,"load",easyscroll);
```

In Safari on iOS, I have to click `btn[0]` and `btn[1]` again to get the scrolling to stop. The desired behaviour is that the scrolling stops as soon as the user removes their finger, having started the scroll with the first touch. The easyscroll library is designed for desktop browsers and I am trying to adapt it to work on iOS too.

Without the modifications, it is impossible to stop the scrolling on a touch device.

Comment: i cant access the link you prvided, have you read this page, http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW24

Comment: You can't use a mouseout on a touch base device, only mousedown and mouseup

Comment: Yes, I realise that - this is why I am trying to replace them with touch events for devices, whilst maintaining the desktop browser functionality